# Integrating a function over the real line

Tags: integration

Let $P(x,z)=(1/pi)(z/(z^2+x^2))$, $x$ in **R** and $z>0$.

Show that the integral of $P(x,z)dx$ over **R**, the real line, is equal to $1$ for $z>0$.

I don't know how to show this, any ideas anyone?

Comment: Substitute $x = z\cdot y$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1\pi\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac z{z^2+x^2}dx=\frac1\pi\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac1zdz\right)}{1+\left(\frac xz\right)^2}=\left.\frac1\pi\arctan\frac xz\right|_{-\infty}^\infty=1$$

The above is based on the following, which you can easily check with the chain rule:

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)^2}=\arctan f(x) +C$$